# MySQL INSERT INTO using Jupyter Notebook ERROR: Invalid syntax

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pymysql

The following code was run in the Jupyter Notebook.

```
import pandas
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='123456', database='sakila')

cursor=connection.cursor()

insert_query= INSERT INTO film_text (film_id, title, description) VALUES ('1001','ZZZ ZORRO','Zorro must Fight a Womanizer in Berlin');

cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

### connection.commit()

ERROR:
  File "", line 7
    insert_query=INSERT INTO film_text (film_id,title,description) VALUES ('1001','ZZZ ZORRO','Zorro must Fight a Womanizer in Berlin');
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please provide the full error message with your code. It will help others find the bug easily.

Comment: Looks like you have the table name surrounded by single quotes.  Table and field names can have backticks but not quotes, single or double.

Comment: I removed the single quotes, and reran, but received another "Invalid Syntax" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly write your code like this

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO film_text (film_id, title, description) VALUES ('1001','ZZZ ZORRO','Zorro must Fight a Womanizer in Berlin'""");
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to wrap the query in quotes. The following code should work perfectly:

```
import pandas
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='123456', database='sakila')

cursor=connection.cursor()

insert_query= "INSERT INTO film_text (film_id, title, description) VALUES ('1001','ZZZ ZORRO','Zorro must Fight a Womanizer in Berlin');"

cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of insert_query will be a string.

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO film_text (film_id, title, description) VALUES ('1001','ZZZ ZORRO','Zorro must Fight a Womanizer in Berlin')"
```

Comment: Putting double quotes around the insert_query, to make it a string, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should warp the query string in quote

```
insert_query= "INSERT INTO film_text (film_id, title, description) 
      VALUES ('1001','ZZZ ZORRO','Zorro must Fight a Womanizer in Berlin')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If don't plan to do highly advanced stuff with the data from python, maybe it's better to use a jupyter [kernel](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb_kernel) to play with the database in plain SQL.